# Next rule action not getting triggered when returning SlotSet in custom action in Rasa 2

Tags: chatbot, rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I have the following rule:

```
- rule: submit form
  condition:
  - active_loop: user_offer_form
  steps:
  - action: user_offer_form
  - active_loop: null
  - slot_was_set:
    - requested_slot: null
  - action: action_get_offer
  - action: utter_ask_deal
```

And here is the custom action:

```
class ActionGetOffer(Action):
def name(self) -> Text:
    return "action_get_offer"

def run(self,dispatcher,tracker: Tracker,domain: "DomainDict",) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

    dispatcher.utter_message(text = "Ok! Let me see what I can do!")


    product_price = 500
    platform_bargain_percentage = 5
    vendor_bargain_percentage = 5
    max_bargain = platform_bargain_percentage + vendor_bargain_percentage

    offer_price = int(tracker.get_slot("price"))
    print(offer_price)

    user_asked_percentage = (offer_price / product_price) * 100

    current_bargain = tracker.get_slot('current_bargain') + 2
    print(current_bargain)



    if user_asked_percentage > current_bargain:

    
        dispatcher.utter_message(text = "Okay so I just checked and sorry but we can't give away for that price!")

        if tracker.get_slot('current_bargain_price') == 0:
            current_bargain_price = (product_price - (((current_bargain)/100) * product_price))
        else:
            current_bargain_price = tracker.get_slot('current_bargain_price')

        if current_bargain <= max_bargain:
            dispatcher.utter_message(text = f"How about {str( product_price - (((current_bargain)/100) * product_price))}?")
        else:
            dispatcher.utter_message(text = "Hmm...wanna make a fresh offer then?")


        # dispatcher.utter_message(response = 'utter_ask_deal')
        return[SlotSet("current_bargain", value = float(current_bargain))]
```

And here is the utter_ask_deal:

```
  utter_ask_deal:
    - text: "Ok with this deal?"
      buttons:
      - title: "Yup"
        payload: '/inform_intent{{"deal":"true"}}'
      - title: "Nope"
        payload: '/inform_intent{{"deal":"false"}}'
```

The rule is executing until `action_get_offer` but the `utter_ask_deal` is not getting executed, and the slot `‘current_bargain’` is also not getting updated.

Interestingly, when I’m not using `SlotSet` in the return statement but using it in the code directly, the next action is being executed but the slot is not updated in both cases.

Can someone help, please?

Comment: Hey, do you see the action `action_get_offer` being executed in your action server log (and could you share the relevant log output perhaps - ideally in debug mode).

Comment: Hi @tttthomasssss! Here is the server log output. The action action_get_offer is being executed.
`2021-11-25 13:52:25 DEBUG    rasa_sdk.executor  - Received request to run 'action_get_offer'      
250
2
2021-11-25 13:52:25 DEBUG    rasa_sdk.executor  - Finished running 'action_get_offer'`
But the next action which is utter_ask_deal is not executed though.

Comment: do you see it getting predicted (ideally by `RulePolicy`) in the rasa server log?

Comment: @tttthomasssss No. Here is the log `2021-11-25 13:52:25 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Predicted next action 'action_listen' with confidence 1.00.
2021-11-25 13:52:25 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Policy prediction ended with events '[]'.
2021-11-25 13:52:25 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Action 'action_listen' ended with events '[]'.      
2021-11-25 13:52:25 DEBUG    rasa.core.lock_store  - Deleted lock for conversation '5839dd9c04734d25bf67dacb364a2978'.
`

Comment: I think you should reset the "current_bargain" value before setting a new value, because the action_loop detect the "current_bargain" slot is not null. check this link: https://forum.rasa.com/t/how-to-replace-update-slots-value/49392

Answer (score 0):

the bot utterance `utter_ask_deal` has indentations issues around the `buttons` tag, try changing it to this:

```
utter_ask_deal:
- text: "Ok with this deal?"
  buttons:
  - title: "Yup"
    payload: '/inform_intent{{"deal":"true"}}'
  - title: "Nope"
    payload: '/inform_intent{{"deal":"false"}}'
```

More information can be collected from here: https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/responses/#buttons

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. However, it was just a formatting error while copy-pasting the code into stack overflow and the indentation is perfectly fine in the code file. I corrected the error in the original question.

Comment: No worries. You're welcomed :)